# How to hide specific cells in a static UItableview, in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

No article explains it clearly regarding my query, I have three cells in a static table and I want to hide second cell when users taps on first cell. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: may i know why was this down voted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although you cannot stop the static table from trying to show your cells, you can set their height to zero, making them effectively invisible:

Add this method to your table view controller delegate class:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell == myHiddenCell ? 0 :  super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
}
```

Comment: "cell == myHiddenCell ? 0"  I don't quite get what this statement is?

Comment: @Tomiris This is Swift's [*Ternary Operator*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html).

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath can be called before cell is created so this answer isn't valid

Comment: @eonist You can always make it work. I did, along with about a dozen people, and it worked for us.

Comment: Yepp, it has worked in the past. Not anymore since iOS 13. You get a long waning in the log. I found a workaround tho: let cell = tableView.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UITableViewCell).first { $0.indexPath = indexPath(for: indexPath) }

Comment: I made an extension which can be used: https://gist.github.com/eonist/deede5d92330e03aa2c7e754cb30173b

Answer (score 0):

In the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` method, you can set the height to 0 to hide it :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 1, inSection : 0)
        let secondCell = tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        secondCell.frame.size.height = 0;
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

If you want an animation, just put `self.view.layoutSubviews()` in an UIView animation method `UIView.animateWithDuration`... etc

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the height to 0 for some cells and another height for other cells wasn't an option, as all my cells have different height.

I created another cell in Storyboard, and set row height of 0 (in size inspector). Then in the code, I show the cell with height = 0 if I want to hide it, if not, I show the other cell:

```
if (hideCell) {
            let hiddenCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hiddenCell",for: indexPath) as! TheWallTableViewCell
            return hiddenCell
        }
else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",for: indexPath) as! TheWallTableViewCell
        return cell 
}
```